# Windows 10 update doesn't start after update from windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, boot

I recieve the windows 10, download it and start the update. It started copying data and on 8 percent or something like that made a restart. After the restart the
PC started and I recieve the message:

> Reboot and select proper Boot divice or select media in selected boot
>   device and press a key

So what are my options now, is this is normal?

- Is the update failed by some reason or I should insert disk/usb of windows 10. I don't have any.
- If the update failed can I somehow repair the windows 7 ?  I don't have Windows 7 at home :) I have access only to BIOS.

What I had try:
Try to put, only the hard disk as boot device. Doesn't work.

The restart happen on this point, after first restart I recieve this message: http://images.gizmag.com/gallery_lrg/upgrade-windows-7-to-windows-10-7.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can go to http://microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10 and download the install utility. With this, you can make a bootable usb stick or DVD with the install media from another pc.

Create such and use that to install your windows again. If you use the same language and version as your corrupted windows 7 to 10 install, it should still allow you to upgrade it and fix the problem. Otherwise you'll be asked if you want to do a clean install, which means that you will have your files, but not the settings and apps installed.

Do note, you will need your serial for your windows 7.

Comment: I receive very helpful error message  from MediaCreationTool: Something happen .... I download it from windows 8.1, start the installation file and this happen.

Comment: Why install the technical preview? The real version is out now. You can get it using the link I provided. The technical preview still had some bugs.

Comment: I install the version from windows update. I don't know if this was real deal or technical preview. I put the screenshot from another article as hint were the process gone wrong. About your link when I try to install this tool, I received error message something happen and close button.

Comment: Oh, its not your screenshot. Then disregard my previous comment. If it fails there... hmm.. Haven't had an install where it failed there. Sorry can't help you then.

Comment: I tried from another PC, now I don't have the error. At the moment I'm creating the iso file. Next step will be to check how to boot from usb :) Hope I don't need to make clean reboot. For architecture I choose both(x32 x64), because I don't remember my windows 7. I upvote you and I will make the answer as correct just I want to see the end of this installation process.

Comment: Good luck. :) You can boot from USB through the bios bootorder setting or boot menu if your bios has a key for that. (usually F11 or esc)